# find command for the newest 500 files in a directory tree and also be POSIX compliant

Tags: files, find, perl, timestamps, posix

I am looking for a single line shell script or unix command to find the newest 500 files in a directory. Major constraints are it should be POSIX complaint and the directory can have tons of files.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you will need to stat every file in the directory in order to determine which are the 500 newest ones.

[`ls -t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ls.html)`| head -n 500`

Comment: [Assuming the file names only contain printable characters other than newlines.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) Doing this in the general case with only POSIX features is difficult.

Comment: Which is why they're talking about banning control characters in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean files in the directory and all its subdirectories, something like

```
find . -exec sh -c \
    $'echo "$(stat -c "%Y" "$0")\t$0"' {} \; | \
    sort -k1nr | cut -f 2 | head -n 500
```

ought to do the trick.

Breaking it down:

- `find . -exec` runs a command on every file below the current directory
- `sh -c "command" {}` runs `command` for each file that `find` sees, with `$0` set to the file name
- `stat -c "+%Y" "$0"` prints the modification time of the file specified in `"$0"`
- `sort -k1nr` sorts based on the first field in reverse numerical order
- `cut -f 2` strips out the modification time field, leaving only the file name
- `head -n 500` prints at most the top 500 lines

The `$'...'` and `\t` are because `sort` and `cut` use `\t` (i.e. TAB) as the field delimiter.

To be POSIX compliant, you can replace

```
$'...\t...'
```

with

```
"...<press Ctrl-V, Tab>..."
```

Unfortunately, `stat` isn't portable.  Linux uses `stat -c "%Y"` but FreeBSD and Mac OS use `stat -f "%m"`.

If you really want a portable method, it would be easier to use Python, Perl, or Ruby.

Comment: yep stat was useful until this POSIX constarint came along.